# Regex: search from variants, but search by variant first, not by searcgin string

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, we have '1+2-3'. And we need to catch symbols [-|+]

```
'1+2-3'.match(/-|+/)
```

returns +, as it trace by string first;
how to find '-' first?
Or, for example, how to implement regex equivalent of:

```
if (match(/-/)) ...
else if (match(/+/) ...
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using regex? Just store `['-', '+']` in array and do `indexOf` using each element in array.

Comment: Your problem is vague. Are you going to parse this string to build a AST?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera kinda of :) , but very simplifiied version

Comment: @PavelShamparov, then your approach is not correct. Have you given grammar rules for your task? Write functions for those rules to achieve it. Top-down parsing would be an easy approach.